# Setting iOS Today Extension bundle version to Flutter FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, plist

I have a flutter application, that also has an iOS native Today extension.

When I change the version on the project's yaml, the "Runner" target gets its version automatically, but the extension target needs to be updated manually.

Is there a way to automate it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you need to update the extension `Info.plist` files with Flutter params:

```
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

Now you need to have these Flutter parameters available for the widget. To do so, you need to include `Flutter/Generated.xcconfig` file in the Extension configuration file. On Xcode, select Project->Runner-, under “info” open “configurations”, [image2] Look for the Extension configuration file, and add the following: #include “Generated.xcconfig” Run ‘`flutter clean`; `flutter run`’ and the version should be updated

Comment: I had to manually add some `xcconfig` files for my extension, but your answer saved me. Thank you!

Comment: In addition to this, I also had to go into the Build Settings of the Extension's target and change the values of `Current Project Version` and `Marketing Version`

Answer (score 0):

if you have change version extension/package in pubspec.yaml, before you run project on XCode, you can try update your pod first, open `cd project/ios/` and hit `pod install --repo-update` so your pod on XCode already update with new version package